# Angular 2 unit testing components with routerLink

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing, angular2-testing

I am trying to test my component with angular 2 final, but I get an error because the component uses the `routerLink` directive. I get the following error:

> Can't bind to 'routerLink' since it isn't a known property of 'a'.

This is the relevant code of the `ListComponent` template

```
<a 
  *ngFor="let item of data.list" 
  class="box"
  routerLink="/settings/{{collectionName}}/edit/{{item._id}}">
```

And here is my test.

```
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { ListComponent } from './list.component';
import { defaultData, collectionName } from '../../config';
import { initialState } from '../../reducers/reducer';


const data = {
  sort: initialState.sort,
  list: [defaultData, defaultData],
};

describe(`${collectionName} ListComponent`, () => {
  let fixture;
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        ListComponent,
      ],
    }).compileComponents(); // compile template and css;
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ListComponent);
    fixture.componentInstance.data = data;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should render 2 items in list', () => {
    const el = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement;
    expect(el.querySelectorAll('.box').length).toBe(3);
  });
});
```

I looked at several answers to similar questions but could not find a solution that worked for me.

Answer (score 130, accepted):

You need to configure all the routing. For testing, rather than using the `RouterModule`, you can use the `RouterTestingModule` from `@angular/router/testing`, where you can set up some mock routes. You will also need to import the `CommonModule` from `@angular/common` for your `*ngFor`. Below is a complete passing test

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { Location, CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
import { TestBed, inject, async } from '@angular/core/testing';

@Component({
  template: `
    <a routerLink="/settings/{{collName}}/edit/{{item._id}}">link</a>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  `
})
class TestComponent {
  collName = 'testing';
  item = {
    _id: 1
  };
}

@Component({
  template: ''
})
class DummyComponent {
}

describe('component: TestComponent', function () {
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        CommonModule,
        RouterTestingModule.withRoutes([
         { path: 'settings/:collection/edit/:item', component: DummyComponent }
        ])
      ],
      declarations: [ TestComponent, DummyComponent ]
    });
  });

  it('should go to url',
    async(inject([Router, Location], (router: Router, location: Location) => {

    let fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestComponent);
    fixture.detectChanges();

    fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('a')).nativeElement.click();
    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
      expect(location.path()).toEqual('/settings/testing/edit/1');
      console.log('after expect');
    });
  })));
});
```

### UPDATE

Another option, if you just want to test that the routes are rendered correctly, without trying to navigate...

You an just import the `RouterTestingModule` without configuring any routes

```
imports: [ RouterTestingModule ]
```

then just check that the link is rendered with the correct URL path, e.g.

```
let href = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('a')).nativeElement
    .getAttribute('href');
expect(href).toEqual('/settings/testing/edit/1');
```

Comment: Thanks, this helps already alot, but I cannot get the unit test to fail. It seems that the because of `async` everything in this block is ginored. I tried to add a done function to the `it('...', (done) => {async(... done())}` but then I get `Error: Timeout` from the test.

Comment: My bad, I had the `async` wrapped in another function and not as second parameter of the `it`. It works now, thanks.

Comment: This is fantastic. Finally found an answer that applies to 2.0 Final (I'm using 2.1)! Since I was going to need the same configuration in a lot of tests, I created a test-only module that configured RouterTestingModule and declared the DummyComponent. Then I put that module and the DummyComponent into a test/ subfolder, which I can then import into any of my unit tests. Thanks @peeskillet

Comment: Actually, if you only need to render routerLink you don't have to setup the routing

Comment: Very thorough and solid answer, thank you. Resolves all routerLink testing issues I saw.

Comment: `getAttribute('href')` returns `null` for me, while it works in app. Is there something I miss?

Comment: @Paul Samsotha do you know how to do the same with providers array? I could not get this working

Answer (score 23):

If you are not testing router related stuff, you can configure the test to ignore unknown directives with 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA'

```
 import { NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
 TestBed.configureTestingModule({
   declarations: [
     ListComponent,
   ],
   schemas: [ NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA ]
 });
```

Comment: Thanks that is even a more specific solution to my problem, thoug I learned also form the first one. Could you please also share where to import `NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA` from.

Comment: `NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA` is currently [flagged](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA-let.html) as `Experimental`

Comment: @CalvinDale That shouldn't matter. A lot of things are marked experimental (including commonly used classes like Http). https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/#!?status=experimental

Comment: You should pretty much never use `NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA` it does a lot more than just fix this. It also causes ALL errors to pass in tests

Answer (score 12):

To write a test case for `routerLink`. You can follow the below steps.

1. Import `RouterTestingModule` and `RouterLinkWithHref`.

   ```
   import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
   import { RouterLinkWithHref } from '@angular/router';
   ```
2. Import `RouterTestingModule` in your module

   ```
   TestBed.configureTestingModule({
     imports: [ RouterTestingModule.withRoutes([])],
     declarations: [ TestingComponent ]
   })
   ```
3. In test case find the directive `RouterLinkWithHref` tot test for the existence of the link.

   ```
   it('should have a link to /', () => {
     const debugElements = fixture.debugElement.queryAll(By.directive(RouterLinkWithHref));
     const index = debugElements.findIndex(de => {
       return de.properties['href'] === '/';
     });
     expect(index).toBeGreaterThan(-1);
   });
   ```

Comment: The import work also as `imports: [ RouterTestingModule ]`

Comment: `linkDes = fixture.debugElement.queryAll(By.directive(RouterLinkWithHref));
  routerLinks = linkDes.map(de=>de.injector.get(RouterLinkWithHref));
  expect(routerLinks[0].href).toBe('/settings/testing/edit/1');`

Answer (score 0):

### How to check that the Router actually triggered the URL change

---

Solution inspired by https://medium.com/@douglascaina/angular-tdd-how-to-test-routerlink-or-url-change-494f18208443

---

My setup (using `ng-mocks`):

```
class MockComponent {}

// ...

MockBuilder(MyComponent)
  .keep(RouterTestingModule.withRoutes([{ path: 'my/path', component: MockComponent }]))
  .keep(RouterLink)
```

My test case:

```
it('when clicked, myLinkElement should lead to /my/path', fakeAsync(() => {
  const { page, router } = setup();
  page.detectChanges();

  page.click(page.myLinkElement().nativeElement);
  tick();

  expect(router.url).toEqual('/my/path');
}));
```