# Can't bind to 'routerLink' since it isn't a known property of 'a'. ("<header id="header">

Tags: angular

This has been asked before and I did all the suggested comments but none seem to work. I am having a combo of an issue. Getting wallaby.js to work with my project and figure out the error when I run `ng test`.

```
Can't bind to 'routerLink' since it isn't a known property of 'a'. ("<header id="header">                                                                                         <h1 id="logo">                                                                                                                                                                    <a [ERROR ->][routerLink]="['/home']"></a>                                                                                                        
                </h1>
        "): AppComponent@2:5
        Can't bind to 'routerLink' since it isn't a known property of 'a'. ("
                <div id="menu">
                        <a [ERROR ->][routerLink]="['/home']" class="btn">Home</a>
                        <a [routerLink]="['/about']" class="btn">About</a>
                        "): AppComponent@6:5
        Can't bind to 'routerLink' since it isn't a known property of 'a'. ("
                <div id="menu">
                        <a [routerLink]="['/home']" class="btn">Home</a>
                        <a [ERROR ->][routerLink]="['/about']" class="btn">About</a>
                        <a [routerLink]="['/experiments']" class="btn">Expe"): AppComponent@7:5
        Can't bind to 'routerLink' since it isn't a known property of 'a'. ("terLink]="['/home']" class="btn">Home</a>
                        <a [routerLink]="['/about']" class="btn">About</a>
                        <a [ERROR ->][routerLink]="['/experiments']" class="btn">Experiments</a>
                </div>
        "): AppComponent@8:5
        'router-outlet' is not a known element:
        1. If 'router-outlet' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
        2. If 'router-outlet' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("
        <div id="container">
                [ERROR ->]<router-outlet></router-outlet>
        </div>
        "): AppComponent@18:1
```

My NgModule

```
import {BrowserModule} from "@angular/platform-browser";
import {NgModule,CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA} from "@angular/core";
import {FormsModule} from "@angular/forms";
import {HttpModule} from "@angular/http";
import {RouterModule} from "@angular/router";
import {HomeComponent} from "./home/home.component";
import {ExperimentsComponent} from "./experiments/experiments.component";
import {AboutComponent} from "./about/about.component";
import {AppComponent} from "./app.component";
import {ExperimentsService} from "./common/experiments.service";
import {StateService} from "./common/state.service";
import {ExperimentDetailComponent} from "./experiments/experiment-details/experiment.detail.component";

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        AboutComponent,
        HomeComponent,
        ExperimentsComponent,
        ExperimentDetailComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot([
            {path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full'},
            {path: 'home', component: HomeComponent},
            {path: 'about', component: AboutComponent},
            {path: 'experiments', component: ExperimentsComponent},
            {path: '**', component: HomeComponent}
        ])
    ],
    schemas: [
      CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA
    ],
    providers: [
        ExperimentsService,
        StateService
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

This is the only module. It is a simple application:

[image]

[image]

I have also posted the project on GitHub [HERE](https://github.com/drewjocham/TestDemo.git)

--------------------- Answer and the explanation is below------------

```
import { TestBed, async } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import {RouterTestingModule} from "@angular/router/testing";
import {HomeComponent} from "./home/home.component";
import {AboutComponent} from "./about/about.component";
import {ExperimentsComponent} from "./experiments/experiments.component";

describe('AppComponent', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        RouterTestingModule.withRoutes([
          {path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full'},
          {path: 'home', component: HomeComponent},
          {path: 'about', component: AboutComponent},
          {path: 'experiments', component: ExperimentsComponent},
          {path: '**', component: HomeComponent}
        ])
      ],
      declarations: [
        AppComponent
      ],
    });
    TestBed.compileComponents();
  });

  it('should create the app', async(() => {
    let fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    let app = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
    expect(app).toBeTruthy();
  }));
});
```

However now I am getting `Failed: Component HomeComponent is not part of any NgModule or the module has not been imported into your module.
        Error: Component HomeComponent is not part of any NgModule or the module has not been imported into your module.`

But HomeCompenent is clearly in my `@NgModule`

Comment: Please share your test file, your ng test is not using this files

Comment: I guess you need to add RouterModule to your test file that is using the routerLink

Comment: The contents of your `AppModule` does not matter for your tests. You'll need to import (& declare) everything that you need for your component in your *.spec.ts-File again

Comment: @benny_boe please see my updated post

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is your app.component.spec.ts

You should also add routerModule there

```
beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent
      ],
      imports:[RouterModule.forRoot([])] //add the router module here as well
    });
    TestBed.compileComponents();
  });
```

When you're testing your AppComponent , like I said , you should give the test bed what ever you've given to your root `@NgModule` , so :

```
 beforeEach( () => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule( {
        imports : [
            BrowserModule,
            FormsModule,
            HttpModule,
            RouterTestingModule.withRoutes( [
                { path : '', redirectTo : '/home', pathMatch : 'full' },
                { path : 'home', component : HomeComponent },
                { path : 'about', component : AboutComponent },
                { path : 'experiments', component : ExperimentsComponent },
                { path : '**', component : HomeComponent }
            ] )
        ],
        declarations : [
            AppComponent,
            AboutComponent,
            HomeComponent,
            ExperimentsComponent,
            ExperimentDetailComponent
        ],

        schemas : [
            CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA
        ],
        providers : [
            ExperimentsService,
            StateService
        ]
    } );
    TestBed.compileComponents();
} );
```

Comment: Please see my update. This seemed to as well take care of routerLink error but now it is saying my `HomeComponent` is not in my `@NgModule` when it clearly is.

Comment: @Drew1208 , dude , if you're going to test app.component , you should define everything you've defined in you NgModule

Comment: Why would you wan't to test your AppComponent anyway, that's really time consuming , you should do unit testing, testing the whole app is more like end to end testing

Comment: You are absolutely right. This is e2e what I am trying to do. I am still getting familiar with testing Angular 2 testing.

Answer (score 8):

When you use the `TestBed` you are configuring a module *from scratch*. In your current configuration, all you have is

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
});
```

So all that's included in the module for the test environment is the `AppComponent`. Nothing from the `AppModule` is included.

So you're getting the error because you are missing all the router directives that are included in the `RouterModule`. You could import the `RouterModule`, but for tests, you should instead use the `RouterTestingModule`

```
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/core/testing'

TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  imports: [
    RouterTestingModule.withRoutes([])
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
});
```

You can add routes to the `withRoutes`.

**See Also:**

- [Angular 2 unit testing components with routerLink](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39577920/2587435)

Comment: Please my updated post. I think you are right one point, thank you.

Comment: Please read the very first sentence of my post. That means you need add anything required for testing just like you would in a normal module

Comment: Basically, if you added your routes to the RouterTestingModule, then you need to declare the corresponding components that go with those routes

Comment: For testing though you probably don't want to add the real component. Just use mock components. See the example link

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue too, and I was using a self-created mock router.

All examples of using/importing the `routing`, `router`,  `RouterTestingModule.withRoutes([])` etc just gave me more errors.

The solution for me was too create a mock for the `routerLink` directive (I'm not sure where the implementation is found when you don't mock the router but use the `RouterTestingModule`, probably in the `RouterTestingModule` itself?)

So in hindsight I could have created the mock myself, but as they say "The real RouterLinkDirective is quite complicated and entangled with other components and directives of the RouterModule. It requires challenging setup to mock and use in tests."

I found the implementation for it at the Angular documentation page here: https://angular.io/guide/testing-components-scenarios#routerlink

As links can go away, I post the code here:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[routerLink]'
})
export class RouterLinkDirectiveStub {
  @Input('routerLink') linkParams: any;
  navigatedTo: any = null;

  @HostListener('click')
  onClick() {
    this.navigatedTo = this.linkParams;
  }
}
```