# Angular 2 Unit Testing - Cannot read property 'root' of undefined

Tags: unit-testing, angular

**Error Description**

Angular version: 2.3.1

My unit test fails to create the component - I know this issue is related to the `[routerLink]` and `[routerLinkActive]` directives because removing them from the template allows the test to create the component.

**TEMPLATE**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="navbar-header">
  <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#iotahoe-top-navigation">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" [routerLink]="['/']">IoTahoe</a>
</div>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="iotahoe-top-navigation">
  <ul *ngIf="isAuthenticated()" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li [routerLinkActive]="['active']"><a [routerLink]="['/dashboard']">Dashboard</a></li>
    <li [routerLinkActive]="['active']"><a [routerLink]="['/browse']">Browse</a></li>
    <li [routerLinkActive]="['active']"><a [routerLink]="['/admin']">Admin</a></li>
    <li [routerLinkActive]="['active']"><a (click)="onLogout()" style="cursor: pointer;">Logout</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**TYPESCRIPT**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthenticationService } from   '../../authentication/authentication.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
moduleId: module.id.toString(),
selector: 'app-top-navbar',
templateUrl: './top-navbar.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./top-navbar.component.css']
})
export class TopNavbarComponent implements OnInit {

constructor(private authenticationService: AuthenticationService, private router: Router) { }

ngOnInit() {
}

isAuthenticated() {
    return this.authenticationService.isLoggedIn;
}

onLogout() {
    this.authenticationService.logout().subscribe(() => {
        return this.router.navigate(['/login']);
    });
}

}
```

**TEST SPEC**

```
/* tslint:disable:no-unused-variable */
import {async, ComponentFixture, TestBed, inject} from '@angular/core/testing';
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {DebugElement, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA, Component} from '@angular/core';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
import { Location, CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { TopNavbarComponent } from './top-navbar.component';
import { AuthenticationService } from '../../authentication/authentication.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import {ReactiveFormsModule} from "@angular/forms";

@Component({
template: ''
})
class DummyComponent {
}


describe('TopNavbarComponent', () => {
let component: TopNavbarComponent;
let fixture: ComponentFixture<TopNavbarComponent>;
let authenticationService: AuthenticationService;

beforeEach(async(() => {
    const authenticationServiceStub = {
        isLoggedIn: false
    };

    const routerStub = {
        navigate: jasmine.createSpy('navigate'),
        navigateByUrl: jasmine.createSpy('navigateByUrl')
    };

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        declarations: [ TopNavbarComponent, DummyComponent ],
        imports:[CommonModule, ReactiveFormsModule,     RouterTestingModule.withRoutes(
            [
                { path: '/', component:DummyComponent },
                { path: '/login', component:DummyComponent },
                { path: '/dashboard', component:DummyComponent },
                { path: '/browse', component:DummyComponent },
                { path: '/admin', component:DummyComponent }
            ])],
        providers: [
            { provide: AuthenticationService, useValue: authenticationServiceStub },
            { provide: Router, useValue: routerStub }
            ]
    }).compileComponents();
}));

beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TopNavbarComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    authenticationService = TestBed.get(AuthenticationService);
    fixture.detectChanges();
});

it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
});
});
```

**ERROR**

> zone.js:155 Uncaught Error: Error in package:407:9:6 caused by: Cannot
>   read property 'root' of undefined
>       at ViewWrappedError.Error (native)
>       at ViewWrappedError.ZoneAwareError (localhost:9876/base/src/test.ts:133296:33)
>       at ViewWrappedError.BaseError [as constructor] (localhost:9876/base/src/test.ts:35630:16)
>       at ViewWrappedError.WrappedError [as constructor] (localhost:9876/base/src/test.ts:35695:16)
>       at new ViewWrappedError (localhost:9876/base/src/test.ts:68018:16)
>       at DebugAppView._rethrowWithContext (localhost:9876/base/src/test.ts:108242:23)
>       at DebugAppView.create (localhost:9876/base/src/test.ts:108142:18)
>       at DebugAppView.View_TopNavbarComponent_Host0.createInternal (/DynamicTestModule/TopNavbarComponent/host.ngfactory.js:16:19)
>       at DebugAppView.AppView.createHostView (localhost:9876/base/src/test.ts:107700:21)
>       at DebugAppView.createHostView (localhost:9876/base/src/test.ts:108156:52)
>       at ComponentFactory.create (localhost:9876/base/src/test.ts:49830:25)
>       at initComponent (localhost:9876/base/src/test.ts:6425:53)
>       at ZoneDelegate.invoke (localhost:9876/base/src/test.ts:132727:26)
>       at ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (localhost:9876/base/src/test.ts:95802:39)
>       at ZoneDelegate.invoke (localhost:9876/base/src/test.ts:132726:32)Zone.runTask @
>   zone.js:155ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:345data.args.(anonymous function)
>   @ zone.js:1376

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `routerLink` directives need a real router, but you are mocking it. A couple things I can see you doing:

- If you don't plan to click the links during testing, then you can mock those directive to just make "noop" directives so the compiler doesn't complain. e.g.

  ```
  @Directive({
      selector: '[routerLink], [routerLinkActive]'
  })
  class DummyRouterLinkDirective {}
  ```

  Then just add that to the `declarations` of the test module. With this you don't really need to configure the `RouterTestingModule` at all. You could probably get rid of that.
- Also if you don't plan to click test, another option (without needing to create dummy directives is to just ignore the errors of missing directives:

  ```
  schemas: [ NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA ]
  ```

  You would add this to the test module configuration (as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39587397/2587435)). This might not be desirable in some cases, as it could also ignore errors that you actually want detected, which could lead to hard to debug tests.
- If you would actually like to click the links and test routing, then you can use the real router. You can see an example of how you can test the navigation, using the `Location`, as seen in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39579009/2587435).

Comment: Hi, thanks for response, I added the mock directive and included it in the declarations for the test module but the same issue still causes the test to fail.

Comment: Did you remove the RouterTestingModule?

Comment: No I hadn't but when I did it worked! Awesome, thanks for the assistance.

Comment: Come to think of it, I think just importing the `RouterTestingModule` (without the call to `withRoutes`) should work also. I  may be wrong that the real router is needed to just compile. I think maybe calling the `withRoutes` requires the real router. You can try to just import the router testing module, and that way you don't need dummy directives. I think this would be the preferred way

Comment: In my case, my component was importing `ActivatedRoute` as well, and instead of raising an error like `Missing provider for ActivatedRoute`, this root error was raised.

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution with the non-mocked routing worked. But I found out that I also needed to add a

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

to the component using "routerlink active".