# How to test routerLink inside button tag angular2

Tags: angular, jasmine, angular2-routing, angular2-router, routerlink

Button looks like this

```
<button [routerLink]="['/account/recovery','identification']" class="btn btn-default">Back</button>
```

I want to check if url has redirected to `/account/recovery/identification` after the button is clicked

If it was an anchor tag [solution is provided here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39577920/angular-2-unit-testing-components-with-routerlink). My problem is with button tag.

My test spec looks like this.

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
        let ne = new NavigationEnd(0, "/account/recovery/otp", null);       // Create a mock instance for navigation end, utilized within OnInit()
        router = {
            navigate: jasmine.createSpy('navigate'),    // to spy on the url that has been routed
            events: new Observable(observer => {        // last router event that occurred
                observer.next(ne);
            }),

        };
        TestBed
            .configureTestingModule({
                imports: [CoreModule],
                declarations: [OtpComponent],
                providers: [
                    {provide: Router, useValue: router},
                    {provide: ActivatedRoute, useValue: router},
                    {provide: Location, useClass: SpyLocation}, FormBuilder
                ],
                schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
            })
            .overrideComponent(OtpComponent, {
                set: {
                    providers: [
                        {provide: MyModel, useClass: MockModel}
                    ],
                }
            })
            .compileComponents();
    }));

    beforeEach(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(OtpComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
    });

it('Back button click on OTP screen should redirect to identification screen', async(inject([Location], (location: Location) => {

        fixture.detectChanges();

        let buttonElements = fixture.debugElement.queryAll(By.css('button'));   // fetch all the elements with button tag.

        buttonElements[0].nativeElement.click();

        fixture.detectChanges();
        fixture.whenStable().then(
            () => {
                expect(location.path()).toBe(['/account/recovery', 'identification']);     // check if url is routed to identification page after back button is clicked
            }
        );
    })));
```

But it does not give me the result I want, Here is what i got :

```
Chrome 56.0.2924 (Windows 7 0.0.0) OtpComponent Back button click on OTP screen should redirect to identification screen FAILED
        Expected '' to be [ '/account/recovery', 'identification' ].
            at webpack:///src/app/account/registration/otp/otp.component.spec.ts:775:40 <- src/test.ts:124883:37 [ProxyZone]
            at AsyncTestZoneSpec.onInvoke (webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/async-test.js:49:0 <- src/test.ts:98588:39) [ProxyZone]
            at ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/proxy.js:76:0 <- src/test.ts:99280:39) [ProxyZone]
            at Zone.run (webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:113:0 <- src/test.ts:148355:43) [ProxyZone => ProxyZone]
            at webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:535:0 <- src/test.ts:148777:57 [ProxyZone]
Chrome 56.0.2924 (Windows 7 0.0.0): Executed 1 of 147 (1 FAILED) (skipped 146) ERROR (0.96 secs / 0.594 secs)
```

Even `buttonElements[0].nativeElement.click();` does not seem to work because there is no click event registered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39579009/3294944) in the link you shared works for buttons, too. Here's a [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/HBhNwn?p=preview) to play with. I wish there was a way to statically (no-click) inspect router link on the button. I suppose you could inspect its attributes and check 'ng-reflect-router-link', but that feels dirty. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

- Create a lightweight component for test routes (`DummyComponent`). (You can use it multiple times if testing multiple routes.)
- Include `RouterTestingModule.withRoutes([...])` with the dummy component for the paths you're testing in the test module imports.
- Import `Location` and inject it into the test. `RouterTestingModule` uses a mock location strategy so you can inspect changes.

  ```
  @Component({ template: '' })
  class DummyComponent {}

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [AppComponent, DummyComponent],
      imports: [
        RouterTestingModule.withRoutes([
           { path: 'test', component: DummyComponent }
          ])
      ]
    });
  });

  describe('app', () => {
    it('should have a test button', inject([Location], (location) => {
      const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
      const elem = fixture.debugElement;

      const button = elem.query(e => e.name === 'button');
      expect(!!button).toBe(true);
      expect(button.nativeElement.textContent.trim()).toBe('CLICK FOR BUBBLES');

      button.nativeElement.click();
      fixture.detectChanges();
      fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
        expect(location.path()).toBe('/test');
      });
    }));
  });
  ```