# How to correctly mock router?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I'm trying to mock router in my test. I followed the instruction step by step given in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39579009/8558515) but I still get error

> 'Cannot read property 'outlets' of null'

This is what I tried:

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [RouterTestingModule.withRoutes([
                {path:'profile/login',component:ProfileLoginComponent}]
            )],
            declarations: [ ProfileLoginComponent ],
            providers: [
                FormBuilder,AuthModel
            ],
            schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
        })
            .overrideComponent(ProfileLoginComponent, {
                set: {
                    providers: [
                        {provide: AuthModel, useClass: MockAuthModel}      
                    ],
                }
            })
            .compileComponents();
    }));
```

If I remove the code with *routerLink* and *routerLinkActive* in the template, then the test cases work perfectly. Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: it looks like you are giving route to navigate to a named outlet, but angular can't find it. I can't see it in your route... do you have more routes defined somewhere else?

Comment: @JayDeeEss I ran a full project search. I have nothing named 'outlets'. Only thing I could find was <router-outlet>

Comment: ok, can you post your code where you are navigating to your components... either programmatically or in html

Comment: @JayDeeEss <a [routerLink]="[lastReqestedLink]" routerLinkActive="active">Go Back</a>

Comment: _lastReqestedLink_ contains previous url in string format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to solved this problem. I also have answered this question in another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46342813/8558515).

> I found out this error occurs when the `routerLink` is pointing to a
>   null variable. In my case, the property called `favoriteUrl` that i
>   assigned to `routerLink` was null because of the isolated testing
>   environment. So I manually assigned a value to the property in
>   `beforeEach` function and that solved the problem, atleast for me.

Reference : https://stackoverflow.com/a/46342813/8558515